# Como se abren unos archivos planos en python?

Tags: python, txt

Quiero hacer un algoritmo en python que haga lo siguiente:

1 - Abrir 3 archivos planos (.txt) para mostrar por pantalla.
https://github.com/felipedelosh/DataOfRandomPersons

Problema:

El programa me abre a veces 1 solo archivo, a veces 2 archivos y el tercero me bota error.

Nota: si los archivos estan vacios, cargan sin problema.

Pregunta:

el metodo open("dir", t) tiene un limite de archivos que se pueden abrir????

```
"""ALG de carga"""

def chargeInfoDB(self):
        # Try to open fist name of men
        try:
            f = open(self.dir+"\data\dbNAMEMALE.txt", 'r')
            self.dbNameMale = f.read()
            self.dbNameMale = self.dbNameMale.strip()
            self.dbNameMale = self.dbNameMale.split('\n')
            self.controlInfoUpload = True
            f.close()
            f = None
        except:
            self.controlInfoUpload = False
            print('Error in male names')

        print(self.dbNameMale)

        # Try to open first name of women
        try:
            f = open(self.dir+"\data\dbNAMEFEMALE.txt", "r")
            self.dbNameFemale = f.read()
            self.dbNameFemale = self.dbNameFemale.strip()
            self.dbNameFemale = self.dbNameFemale.split("\n")
            self.controlInfoUpload = self.controlInfoUpload and True
            
            f.close()
            f = None
            self.controlInfoUpload = self.controlInfoUpload and True
        except:
            self.controlInfoUpload = self.controlInfoUpload and False
            print('Error in female names')

        # Try to open lastnames
        try:
            # Error i'm only read 2 .txt?
            f = open(self.dir+"\data\dbLASTNAME.txt", "r")
            self.dbLastName = f.read()
            self.dbLastName = self.dbLastName.strip()
            self.dbLastName = self.dbLastName.split("\n")
            
            f.close()
            f = None
            self.controlInfoUpload = self.controlInfoUpload and True
        except:
            self.controlInfoUpload = self.controlInfoUpload and False
            print('Error in last names')
```

Comment: Sospecho que se pueda tratar de un problema de _encoding_ (deberías mostrar el error que te sale). Por defecto Python asume que el contenido de los ficheros viene codificado en utf8. Si no es el caso (lo cual es bastante probable trabajando en Windows) debes especificar el parámetro `encoding` en el `open()`, especificando cuál es el que usan (en Windows sería probablemente `cp-1252`)

Comment: Caballero, dejeme felicitarlo ese era el error. En windows hay que meterle la codificacion UTF-8 ::

f = open(self.dir+"\\data\\dbLASTNAME.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8")